# Does Apple prohibit the display of a non-interactive preview of a system notification on an app's UI?

Tags: ios, notifications, ui, design

I'm on initial design stages of a new iOS app, and for one of the screens I'm thinking of having the user build a custom notification.

For that, the app would feature a preview of the final notification bubble at the bottom of a screen. This notification would have the same appearance of a real notification, but would appear in a place on the screen where a real notification would never be shown. At the end of the flow, the user would confirm the built notification looks as it should, and then it would be dismissed and scheduled as a real notification to appear later on.

Is there any prohibitions in place for a UI with this characteristic? I asked a few friends who work on iOS development, and I've searched through the Human Interface Guidelines on Apple's website, but I didn't find any confirmation of whether this is explicitly disallowed. Somehow, though, I have this nagging feeling that this is the type of stuff that Apple would disallow.

Can anyone confirm whether this is allowed?

Comment: You're just allowing the user to semi-customize the notification, right?  There's not a lot that Apple allows to be changed in the appearance or display of a notification.  You can't for example, allow the user to place the notification anywhere they want on the screen.  Apple only allows them in certain locations.

Comment: Yes. I just want to allow the user to preview a notification they will receive later, and that will be populated (title, byline) by their own input. I guess what I'm really asking is: can you draw a notification on the UI if it's not a *real*, live, active notification? Does Apple prohibit somewhere on their guidelines?

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitations of drawing fake notifications in your UI.  I think you'll be ok.